# ReferenceError: variable is not defined with underscore template

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm making an app with jQuery, jQueryMobile and underscore templates but I've never had this error, I can not find the variables that happened to the templates:

```
    self.$list = $("#list");
    var template = _.template('<%= foo %>', {foo: 'hello'});
    self.$list.html(template);
```

Error: ReferenceError: foo is not defined

This is an example, if I try to render a list of categories I feel the same.

```
    _.each(categories, function(category){
        console.log(category); //<-- ok
        var template = _.template(self.$categoryTemplate.text(), category);
        self.$list.append(template);
    });
```

categoryTemplate:

```
    <script id="category-template" type="text/template">
        <li><a href="#"><% = name %></a></li>
    </script>
```

I do not understand why you do not see the variables in the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call of `_.template` returns a function which takes an object with template variables as the first argument.

So you should do this:

```
self.$list = $("#list");
var template = _.template('<%= foo %>')({foo: 'hello'});
self.$list.html(template);
```

and this:

```
_.each(categories, function(category){
    console.log(category); //<-- ok
    var template = _.template(self.$categoryTemplate.text())(category);
    self.$list.append(template);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works but I do not understand why the above does not work.

Comment: @oscar: The `_.template` interface changed recently, see my answer to the duplicate for details.